# How to pass a custom listview from one activity to another activity in Android without using intent

Tags: android, listview

I need a sample program where I have a custom listview with adapter and when I click on a item on the list view it must be selected and it should be visible in another activity. This should be done without Intent.

Comment: You could use SharedPreferences or SQLite to save your selected item.

Comment: when you say an item is clicked on the list view and then should be made visible in another activity, you mean the entire view changes? Is the list view displayed in a different activity or in a fragment as part of the main activity? I need further clarity. There are many ways to achieve this without using `intent` but it depends on where and how the transition happens,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#q=Shared%20Preference), When you click on any of the item store that data in prefrence and use in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Make your arraylist global in one activity as below:

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity{

  public static ListView list;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);

       list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_LIST_ID);


   ..................
   ..................
  }
}
```

And in other activity fetch it as below:

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity{

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       ListView list=ActivityOne.list.getListView();


       ..................
       ..................
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use untent extends the application class and make property that holds object of what you have selected in list view

```
//pseudocode 
//Application class
class GlobalApp extends Application {

//you need to overirde this method
public void oncreate(parameter) {
 super.onCreate(parameter);
}
public MyClass myObject; // replace MyClass  with datatype need
}

// In activity where you are handling listview make class variable of type GlobalApp

GloabalApp app = (GlobalApp) getApplication();
//in your item selected method  of your list view 

app.myobject = selectedValue

// In another activity on activity method
GloabalApp app = (GlobalApp) getApplication();
Myclass Selectedobj  = app.myobject
```

In manifest file  in your application tag add android:name attribute with value="yourpackagename.GlobalApp"